# Adding a HTMLButton into a HTMLTableCell in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm currently generating a dynamic HTML-Table with the help of ASP.NET.
The generating of the table is working very good but I don't know how I can put a HTMLButton (submitting the information of each row to the DB) into a HTMLTableCell object.

Here is a short code-snippet from my CodeBehind-File:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dokuDaten.Count; i++)
        {
            row = new HtmlTableRow(); //Header Row

            cellVorname = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellVorname.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._VersVorname;
            row.Cells.Add(cellVorname);

            cellNachname = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellNachname.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._VersNachname;
            row.Cells.Add(cellNachname);

            cellGebDatum = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellGebDatum.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._VersGeborenAm;
            row.Cells.Add(cellGebDatum);

            cellVersNr = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellVersNr.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._VersNummer;
            row.Cells.Add(cellVersNr);

            cellBSNR = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellBSNR.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._BSNR;
            row.Cells.Add(cellBSNR);

            cellLANR = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellLANR.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._LANR;
            row.Cells.Add(cellLANR);

            cellDM1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellDM1.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._dm1;
            row.Cells.Add(cellDM1);

            cellDM2 = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellDM2.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._dm2;
            row.Cells.Add(cellDM2);

            cellBRK = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellBRK.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._brk;
            row.Cells.Add(cellBRK);

            cellKHK = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellKHK.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._khk;
            row.Cells.Add(cellKHK);

            cellASTM = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellASTM.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._astm;
            row.Cells.Add(cellASTM);

            cellCOPD = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellCOPD.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._copd;
            row.Cells.Add(cellCOPD);

            cellVersUnterschriftAm = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellVersUnterschriftAm.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._VersUnterschriftAm.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            row.Cells.Add(cellVersUnterschriftAm);

            cellArztUnterschriftAm = new HtmlTableCell();
            cellArztUnterschriftAm.InnerText = dokuDaten[i]._ArztUnterschriftAm;
            row.Cells.Add(cellArztUnterschriftAm);

           

            //Button that I want to implement into the cell
            HtmlButton zuordnungsButton = new HtmlButton();
            zuordnungsButton.ID = "btnZuordnung";
            zuordnungsButton.InnerText = "Zuordnen";
            zuordnungsButton.Attributes.Add("Class","btn btn-success");
            zuordnungsButton.ServerClick += SaveButton_Click;


            //The cell where the button should appear in the end
            cellOptionen = new HtmlTableCell();


            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        TDPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

and also my aspx-file:

```
<div class="form-group-row">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="TDPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>        
</div>
```

My question is: How do I put a HTMLButton into a HTMLTableCell in ASP.NET?
I really hope that you can help me out!

Comment: `cellOptionen.Controls.Add(zuordnungsButton);` is not working? Perhaps you will run into some other problems later, but this should work.

Comment: And of course, add the `cellOptionen` to the row.

Comment: thanks @Homungus it worked! 
I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and I thought that there must be another parameter which adds elements to a cell. 

if you want you can post your answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cellOptionen.Controls.Add(zuordnungsButton);`

Perhaps you will run into some other problems later, but this should work so far.

Perhaps look into some databound controls like `ListView` and so on - they are better to handle than dynamically created controls in asp.net.